# Emulador IOS no Webview (iframe) perdendo a sessão do asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, ionic, ios, apple

Estou com um problema no meu projeto em Ionic, abaixo segue as versões.

> Ionic: **4.1.2**
>   ASP.NET: **2.1.502**

Um pouco sobre meu projeto...

Ele tem uma rota no aplicativo onde gera um `Webview` (iframe) onde nesse webview possuí um módulo onde é possível se cadastrar e logar.

```
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = src;

$('page-reservations ion-content .scroll-content').html(iframe.outerHTML)
```

*[Imagem do Código](http://prntscr.com/lw6r3o)* 
[Imagem do Resultado](http://prntscr.com/lw6rj3)

Ele funciona no browser (`run broswer`), no aparelho (`android` e `ios`), porém em **específico no emulador do IOS (Apple) apenas não está funcionando a parte do login**.

**O problema de não conseguir logar foi encontrado, é que no emulador do IOS** não está mantendo o **Id da Session** gerada no `ASP.NET` fica alterando a cada requisição, fazendo com que o usuário não consiga acessar sua conta, lembrando que está ocorrendo este problema apenas **no emulador do IOS** (Apple), no aparelho real funciona normalmente.

Funciona no iPhone, funciona no Emulador do Android, funciona no Browser, e o aplicativo funciona no Android também.

Gostaria de mais informações e ver se alguém já se deparou com essa situação.

> 1. Existe alguma justificativa para esse ocorrido apenas no emulador da
>      IOS?
> 2. Existe alguma saída para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema resolvido**, o problema não estava nem no Ionic e nem no ASP.NET.

**O que acontecia?**
Emulador IOS no XCode ele não persiste a sessão do ASP.NET no emulador ou seja sempre que você iria logar, a aplicação do Ionic chamava Webview, que neste Webview chamaria API do ASP.NET e criava sessão e devolvia, porém na devolução ele já limpava sessão, então nunca conseguindo acessar a aplicação, isto somente no emulador IOS no XCode, usado em testes de aplicativo pela IOS.

**Qual foi a solução?**
Como a API existia um token na sessão do próprio ASP.NET e ele sempre era limpado, então persisti o token da sessão em uma variável na memoria do front-end, lembrando que já armazena em cookie por padrão esse token, porém era limpado pelo emulador. Assim quando mandava requisição para API mandava token junto, porém dava preferencia para cookie que já vem por padrão do ASP.NET, caso não encontrado utilizava a passada na requisição junto, e se não achasse realmente o usuário não estaria logado.

**Observação**, não é uma boa prática, mas foi um problema onde fez aprender muito, e caso utilizem algum WebView dentro do Ionic que necessita de login, persistir algum tipo de sessão, talvez iram enfrentar este problema.